# C# EF core: Child row gets removed when updating the Parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi guys I have an issue with EF core version 6.4.4.

I am developing an .NET core (3.1) app that is multi-threaded (not the issue but just giving context) using MySQL (8.x) as database.

The issue that I am currently having is that my child row is getting removed when I update the parent row which doesn't cause a crash but it results in data loss as I am collecting data every second to create a chart.

I didn't have this issue initially but when I started adding foreign key constraints, indexes and refactored the code a bit for optimization I suddenly got this issue.

**What I tried**

So at first I thought that EF core set the parent as null when updating another entity or maybe that some required fields where null which resulted in a delete but this was not the case so I tried to use Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore for the ability to perform single updates (meaning that I will only update the given entity and not the referenced enitities aswell) but this didn't fix it.

I also checked all my indexes and foreignkeys to allow duplicates to make sure that I didn't delete a row because it had a duplicate key. All my indexes allowed duplicate rows (by setting unique false).

**Classes**

```
public  class Parent
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public ParentSatus Status { get; set; } //this is the property that I want to update

    public decimal valueX{ get; set; }

    public decimal valueY{ get; set; }
}

public  class Child
{
    
    public  int Id { get; set; }
    public  string Name { get; set; }
    public  decimal SomeValue{ get; set; }
    public  decimal SomeValue2{ get; set; }
    public string IdForExternalAPI { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public ChildStatus Status { get; set; }
    public  ChildType Type { get; set; }
    public  virtual Parent Parent { get; private set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; } //This is for foreignkey constraint stuff see below
}
```

**ModelBuilder**

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasOne(e => e.Parent).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Child>(e => e.ParentId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasIndex(e => e.SomeIndex).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasIndex(e => e.ParentId).IsUnique(false);
    }
```

So obviously the relationship is a none-to-one which might be the cause but I don't want a one-to-one as the parent needs to get referenced by some other classes and the Child is also a parent for some other classes.

Can someone help with this?
I will add the answer if I find it some day.

Also some clarification: I did not add all the extra stuff as they have no part in this issue but will add it if it is necessary.

Edit:

**Code where I update the parent**

```
 foreach (var parent in parentRepository.ReadParents(new Func<Parent, bool>(e => e.Status == Status.ONGOING)).ToList())
        {
            bool isStillOngoing = //Calculate the current status based on other entities
            if (!isStillOngoing)
            {
               //Do some calculations here
            }

            parent.Status = isStillOngoing ? Status.ONGOING : Status.FINISHED;
            //TODO: Bug here that deletes the child
            parentRepository.UpdateParent(parent);
        }
```

Comment: Can you add code where you update parent?

Comment: Are you possibly creating a new Parent instead of updating the existing Parent? EF will cascade-delete if the Parent is removed.

Comment: I updated the question. I am going to test some stuff out now but I will check this post for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it by turning the relationship around. Looks like I was too tired yesterday it should have been a none-to-many.

Fixed by changing the modelbuilder.

**The fix**

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasMany<Child>().WithOne(e=> e.ParentId).HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade).IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasIndex(e => e.SomeIndex).IsUnique(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasIndex(e => e.ParentId).IsUnique(false);
}
```

Thank you all for the help.